# is it possible to create 64 bit program using a 32 bit OS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit

i have 32 bit windows 7 and I am using visual studio 2010 express.

Is it possible to create a solution for a 64 bit platform?

If it is possible, how is it done?

Comment: Not a good question, as the only possible answers are `Yes` or `No`.

Comment: Sure.  Open a hex editor and start typing appropriate opcodes ;-)

Comment: @EricJ. that's neat, have to remember this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write managed code and target AnyCPU, the code will be jitted to appropriate assembly for the platform it's executed on

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasics32bitAnd64bitConfusionAroundX86AndX64AndTheNETFrameworkAndCLR.aspx

To directly target 64 bit apps from Visual Studio *Express*, install Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) in addition to Visual C++ Express.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ["How to: Enable a 64-Bit Visual C++ Toolset at the Command Line"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x4d2c09s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) at MSDN helps, but it's for VS2010 *not* express. Basically it's all about having a cross compiler.

**Edit:** In addition to that, there is also [How to: Configure Visual C++ Projects to Target 64-Bit Platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9yb4317s.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

cl64.exe itself is a 32 bit program. It just produces 64 bit code. In Visual Studio create a Win32 project, and create a new target platform in the configuration manager.